# How to open new activities in the same fragment hosted in TabLayout - Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-tablayout

I am trying to develop an application which has 3 tabs and one of the tab has a listview. I can handle the onclick events for listview items. What I need to know is how to open new activity/fragment in the same tab(without losing Tab bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` and   `SupportFragmentManager` to achieve this. First add by Nuget `Support.V4` package. In your Activity layout add 
`RelativeLayout`, this layout will be keep your fragments. Add new fragments and by using fragment manager you can changing it. Using function ChangeFragment(), You will be only change view in RealitiveLayout. Try follow this sample.

**main.axml**

```
 <!-- The Main Content View -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/SetFragment" />
```

**main_activity.cs**

```
    protected void ChangeFragment(int pos)
    {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (pos)
        {
            case 0:
               fragment = new NotificationFragment();
               break;

            case 1:
                fragment = new SampleFragment();
                break;
        }

            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                .Replace(Resource.Id.SetFragment, fragment, LoadFragment)
                .Commit();
      }
```

**sample_fragment.cs**

```
public class SampleFragment : Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.sampleView, container, false);

        return View;
    }
}
```